# Joining a table in a wrong order

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get my query below to work, I think I have the order of the join placed incorrectly. I have checked my logic and everything makes sense but not sure where should my Join goes because currently its erroring out on line that begins with: "ON"

```
 SELECT B.OB_REGION_ID AS Outbound_REGION,
   C.OB_REGION_ID AS Inbound_REGION ,
   d.Vehicle_size ,
   a.*

 from 
 (Select * from PA_OPT_FNL_PRC_REC )a
 ,pa_outbound B
 ,pa_outbound c
 join PA_Vehicle_class d
 ON a.VEHICLE_CLASS = d.VEHICLE_class
 where 

a.OB_LOCATION_ID = b.OB_PRIMARY_LOCATION 
AND a.IB_LOCATION_ID = c.OB_PRIMARY_LOCATION 
group by B.OB_REGION_ID, C.OB_REGION_ID, d.vehicle_size
```

Comment: Likely has to do with mixing old style and new style joins. I'd start by replacing the old style 'comma' joins with new style `join`. You'll get better answers if you describe exactly what error you're getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix two kinds of joins; switch to explicit one, such as

```
select b.ob_region_id   as outbound_region,
       c.ob_region_id   as inbound_region,
       d.vehicle_size,
       a.*
from (select *
      from pa_opt_fnl_prc_rec
     ) a
join pa_outbound b on a.ob_location_id = b.ob_primary_location
join pa_outbound c on a.id_location_id = c.ob_primary_location
join pa_vehicle_class d on a.vehicle_class = d.vehicle_class
group by b.ob_region_id,
         c.ob_region_id,
         d.vehicle_size;
```

Comment: it says I have an invalid identifier on the last line, would you know why, I don't see anything wrong with it

Comment: I suspect it's saying that because the `d` alias is used, but never defined. It's probably referring to `pa_vehicle_class`.

Comment: Right; I *forgot* to include PA_VEHICLE_CLASS alias, "d". Fixed.